# Sort a list in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am attempting to do some patchwork in a dll that was written in C++

The list is being initialized as below:

```
std::list<const char*> *myList = new std::list<const char*>();
```

Some business logic will fill the list with the strings. I am attempting to sort this list alphabetically.
I've written the below line to sort the list

```
myList ->sort();
```

As a novice to C++, I assume the list would be sorted in place within the container(i.e list). But no sorting is happening on the list. Appreciate any help!

Comment: 1) Sorting a `std::list` is hopelessly inefficient, 2) it will be in place, 3) you ***were*** going to provide your own comparison function, right? Otherwise you'll end up sorting the pointers in the list according to their raw memory address, of course.

Comment: Problem is default comparator compares one `const char *` to another using `<` which is not what you need. You better use `std::string` or `std::string_view` instead of raw `const char *` or use special comparator if you have to use raw pointer - see details in the dup.

Comment: Was working on a generic example when the question was closed. Here you go @bhanucs: https://pastebin.com/0zH9674T

Comment: Unrelated note: A large part of `std::list`'s job is to manage the memory used by the list for you. If you `new` the list, you're taking some of that  work back upon yourself and exposing yourself to the possibility that you will not correctly put the memory away  and "leak it." Any time you see `new` in conjunction with `std::list` odds are extremely high you're looking at a mistake. This also applies to the rest of the [Standard Library Containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)